# I can't run this pure python code with Cuda or njit

Tags: python, numba

I am currently learning how to use numba with decorator and I am trying to run this code with Cuda, I am running Conda Python 3.8 and would like to speed up this code in Cuda or with njit.

With no jit Time Elapsed = 46.5080931186676

with jit Time Elapsed = 42.55301785469055

If I try to run it with @njit getting this error

```
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Untyped global name 'hex': cannot determine Numba type of <class 'builtin_function_or_method'>

    File "main.py", line 7:
    def gen_hex():
        <source elided>
        for i in range(1, 10000000):
            x = hex(i)[2:].zfill(64)
            ^
```

Here is my code

```
from numba import jit
import time

@jit
def gen_hex():
    for i in range(1, 10000000):
        x = hex(i)[2:].zfill(64)
        print(x)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    start = time.time()
    gen_hex()
    end = time.time()
    print("Elapsed = %s" % (end - start))
```

Any suggestion

Comment: what is hex? you need to define it in the file or you need to import it

Comment: hex is pure python, convert decimal to hexadecimal,  hex() function converts an integer to the corresponding hexadecimal number in string form and returns it.

Comment: There are various aspects of python which may not be supported in various dialects of numba.  `hex` would appear to be one of them.  Your options would be to not use numba, or else come up with your own realization of `hex` which numba or numba cuda can accept.